# Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the vector space of real polynomials. Define $D(x^n) := nx^{n−1}\text{, for n } \geq 0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the vector space of real polynomials. Define $D(x^n) :=  nx^{n−1} , \text{for } n \geq 0$.

$ \begin{align}
&\text{i) Show that }D \text{ extends to an endomorphism of } \mathbb{R}[x]\\
&\text{ii) Determine } \ker(D^n) \text{ and Im}(D^n), \text{ for each } n \geq 1\\
&\text{iii) Find }E \in End(\mathbb{R}[x]) \text{ such that } DE = I.\text{ Is } ED = I?\\
&\text{iv) Find a subspace } K \neq 0 \text{ of } \mathbb{R}[x] \text{ with }  \mathbb{R}[x]/K \cong \mathbb{R}[x]
\end{align}$

Comment: I dont know where to start.

Comment: The first part is a good idea. Well, do you know the definition of endomorphism? How can you apply it here?

Comment: I know the definition of an endomorphism  but I have no clue how to apply it here.

Comment: Is this map additive? Is it linear? Does it map the domain to itself? That's how you apply it.

Comment: ad i): As the $x^n$ form a basis of $\Bbb R[x]$, any map defined only on these can be extended in a unique way to a linear map. One might say, there is nothing to be shown. - Ad (iii): $D$ schould be recognized as (formal) differentiation. What operation would yo suspect to be more or less inverse to differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) For the first part, $\{x^n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Therefore, every function defined on it which goes to a vector space extends uniquely to a linear transformation. In particular, since $D$ is defined on such basis, it extends. That it is a *endomorphism* is just a matter of the codomain being the domain itself.

ii) If $P \in \ker D$, then $D(P)=0$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ has characteristic $0$, the only way that $D(P)$ will be able to vanish is if $P$ had degree $0$, that is, was a constant. Reciprocally, it is clear that every constant goes to $0$ by $D$. Hence, $\ker D=\{\text{Constant polynomials}\}$.

$\text{Im } D=\mathbb{R}[x]$ is easy to see by (iii), since a map is surjective if and only if it has a right inverse.

iii) Define $E: \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ by defining it on the basis $\{x^n\}$, taking $x^n \mapsto \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, and extending it linearly. This is legal for the same reasons as (i). You will note that $DE=I$, but $ED \neq I$, since constants may vanish.

iv) Use (ii) together with the isomorphism theorem.